# Can you temporarily write-block a specific USB drive in Windows 10 (and not block others)?

Tags: windows-10, usb-storage

Can you write-block a specific USB drive in Windows 10 (and not block others)?

Is there any method in Windows 10, to protect one USB drive or SD card from accidental writing (make it read only), while allowing writing to other USB drives or SD cards?  In short, achieving this:

- USB drive A (destination drive) is writable
- USB drive B (source drive) is write-blocked

DETAILS:

I used to do this with the StorageDevicePolicies/WriteProtect registry key in Windows 7 while running backups.  I'd turn on this key when plugging in the drive I wanted read-only.  Then I'd turn this key off and plug in the destination drive.  In the end I had the source drive protected and the destination drive writable, and could fearlessly run a backup.

But I can't figure out how to do this in Windows 10. My Windows 7 registry keys tactic doesn't seem to work in Windows 10.  What happens is, when I change the WriteProtect key, it doesn't seem to "take" immediately.  So I turn on the WriteProtect key, and plug in the drive, but it's still writable.  I think it sometimes works after reboot, but then both drives will be writable or both blocked.

I've seen at least 3 mentioned ways to do USB write blocking on Windows 10 but I'm not sure if any of them will allow me to do this.  Specifically, is any of these designed to take effect immediately BUT not affect already plugged in drives?

- StorageDevicePolicies/WriteProtect registry key
- USBSTOR registry key
- Local Group Policy Editor > Removable Disks: Deny read access

Or is there some better, more elegant, low risk way of doing this in Windows 10?  My underlying goal is to idiot-proof my backup process and avoid having a situation where I clone the backup drive to the source. Anything that has that general effect might work as well as the registry hack tactic did.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: What method are you using to backup which could possibly result in getting the source & destination confused & which also couldn't just be scripted, batched, or otherwise 'preset'?

Comment: I use robocopy, and sometimes mistype E: and D: swapped.

Comment: BTW, the only solution I know of that exists is the "diskpart" method of write protecting. But I can't bring myself to "protect" a drive I'm after all worried about damaging the data on, by running a *DISK PARTITIONING* command!